# Selecting words in a text using regex

Tags: regex

```
var text = 'word otherword';
```

I want to select words that only matches with 'word'. When i use simply `/word/` for regex pattern, then it also selects the 'word' part in 'otherword'. I dont need that word(in this case 'otherword').So how can i only select/match 'word' word using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) - `\b`.

```
/\bword\b/
```